# Request with zeep (SAOP) using certificate (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, soap, ssl-certificate, suds, zeep

Based on this documentation to use certificates:

https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/transport.html

**My code is:**

```
from zeep import Client as zeepClient
from zeep.transports import Transport
from requests import Session
import os

file_pem = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/file.pem"
session = Session()
session.verify = file_pem
transport = Transport(session=session)
zeepclient = zeepClient('https://myurl.com:8000/demo/services/User?wsdl', transport=transport)
result = zeepclient.service.adUser(payload)
```

It doesn't work.

**Error:**

requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myurl.com', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /demo/services/User?wsdl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

**Example .pem file:**

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxJzAlBgNVBAMTHkRpZ2lDZXJ0IFNIQTIg
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIQAf2j627KdciIQ4tyS8+8kTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBh
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSAwHgYDVQQDExdEaWdpQ2VydCBHbG9iYWwgUm9vdCBD
QTAeFw0xMzAzMDgxMjAwMDBaFw0yM...................................
....................................eNqzqPlt/yGFUzZgTHbO7Djc1lGA
8MXW5dRNJ2Srm8c+cftIl7gzbckTB+6WohsYFfZcTEDts8Ls/3HB40f/1LkAtDdC
2iDJ6m6K7hQGrn2iWZiIq
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: Hi Carlos, did you solver this issue? I'm facing a similar problem, I have to use a SOAP service which requires a certificate to access the service. I have a pem file that I can use successfully with SoapUI-5.6.0. The thing is that when I try to make the call using the `requests` package I get an error because the certificate of the URL I'm pointing to is self-signed. Any comments about how you solved the issue will be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @JordiVidaldeLLobatera! Did you solved the issue? I'm facing the same problem here